# How to remove BOM in Intellij Idea

Tags: ide, utf-8, intellij-idea, byte-order-mark

I'd like to remove Bite Order Masks from my
UTF-8 files in Intellij IDEA, how can I do this?

The problem is that if I'm trying to do it via other editors (e.g. Akelpad),
when I modify the file later in IDEA it somehow remembers that BOM
was present and adds it to my file again (((

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such action to remove BOM from UTF-8 files in IntelliJ IDEA. There was a bug that [BOM is removed](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-47768), but it was fixed a long time ago.

When you remove BOM externally, make sure the file is synchronized with editor, try `File` | `Synchronize`.

If IntelliJ IDEA still thinks that this file has BOM, please [file an issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) with the steps to reproduce.

Comment: +1 for the `File | Synchronize` hint. IntelliJ is not able to aptly recognize external BOM changes, but this helps. Still, any further change to the same file, inside IntelliJ, will bring the BOM back... :-/ (IntelliJ CE 12). AFAIK the only way of making this REALLY annoying behavior go away is 1) closing IntelliJ, 2) remove the *&¨*&#ing BOM and 3) reopening it.

Answer (score 12):

Tested on PHPStorm 8:

Right click on a file in the project tree,
click on "Remove BOM"

(Not sure if it exists on the base platform, comments will be helpful)

Comment: If it's not shown in the file context menu, search for `BOM` in Help -> Find Action.

Comment: With the new UI it's under Tools in the right-click menu

Answer (score 2):

Intellij Idea has an option, File->Remove Bom, but it looks doesn't work very well, I got "This file has mandatory Bom" error

The following tips work for me

> 1) create new empty file (for example: temp123.java)
>
> 2) make sure that code-page/encoding for that file is UTF-8
>
> 3) copy whole content from original to newly created file (select all, copy, go >  to another tab, paste) and save

I referenced link below, can be combined with Intellij Idea File->File Encoding-> Reload/Convert to UTF-8

[IDEs Support: Remove BOM from file - how ?](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207019915-Remove-BOM-from-file-how-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem.

I found this issue and a "works for me"-fix: 
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86880#comment=27-386505

Hope it helps